# Authentication issue after Upgrade Apachet Superset

Tags: apache-superset

We have been trying to Upgrade our staging environment apache superset from 2.4 to 3.0 -  Version, however, right now  as You can see on the image below , We cant proceed with authentication and also I don't know how I can enhance my code in order to generate useful logs and check what happens with the authentication

Do you have any recommendation to help me in this troubleshoot ?

[image]

I have tried to check pod logs and also checking on the `Postgres` `metadada,` but I haven't got any info useful.

```
select dttm , json ,  referrer from logs 
where dttm > current_date - interval '1' day
Order by dttm desc;
```

[image]